# Table unwanted padding

Tags: html, css

**Introduction**

I have this portion of HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
[...]
<table class="inv">
  <tr>
    <td id="i_1"></td><td id="i_2"></td><td id="i_3"></td><td id="i_4"></td><td id="i_5"></td>
    <td class="dt" rowspan="5">
      <div style="height:460px;position:relative">
        <div class="st msg"></div>
        <img src="content/images/site/inv.png"><br>
        <a id="nm">USER INVENTORY</a><br>
        <span class="desc">Contain tradable items of the user, click on an item on the left.</span><br>
        <div style="text-align:right;padding-top:15px" class="bts"></div>
      </div>
      <div id="bot" style="display:none"><span class="bt i_b pp">&lt;</span>&nbsp;<span class="bt i_b np">&gt;</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<span style="font-weight:bold" id="pgs"></span></div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="i_6"></td><td id="i_7"></td><td id="i_8"></td><td id="i_9"></td><td id="i_10"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="i_11"></td><td id="i_12"></td><td id="i_13"></td><td id="i_14"></td><td id="i_15"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="i_16"></td><td id="i_17"></td><td id="i_18"></td><td id="i_19"></td><td id="i_20"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="i_21"></td><td id="i_22"></td><td id="i_23"></td><td id="i_24"></td><td id="i_25"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
[...]
```

Linked to this CSS:

```
body{
  font:16px Arial, Tahoma;
  background-color:#222222;
  margin:auto;
  width:100%;
}
table{
  border-collapse:collapse;
  color:#FFF;
  width:100%;
}
table td{
  border:1px solid #FFFFFF;
  vertical-align:top;
  text-align:left;
  padding:0px;
}
.inv{
  table-layout:fixed;
}
.inv td:not(.dt){
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  text-align:center;
  vertical-align:middle;
}
.inv td:not(.dt) > img{
  max-width:100px;
  max-height:100px;
  cursor:pointer;
}
.inv td:not(.dt) > img:hover{
  position:absolute;
  z-index:100;
  width:110px;
  height:auto;
  margin-top:-55px;
  margin-left:-55px;
  box-shadow:0px 0px 2px 1px #000000;
}
.inv .dt{
  width:35%;
  padding:10px;
}
.inv .dt img{
  width:100%;
  height:auto;
}
.inv .dt #desc{
  font-size:12px;
  color:#B8B6B4;
  max-height:60px;
  overflow:hidden;
  display:inline-block;
}
.bt.i_b{
  color:#FFFFFF;
}
.bt.i_b:hover{
  background-color:#1B1B1B;
}
.det #nm{
  font-size:20px;
  font-weight:bold;
}
```

All the TDs inside the table are filled with images with this code:

```
for(var i = 0; i < ((inv.length < 25) ? inv.length : 25); i++){
  $("td#i_"+(i + 1)).html('<img src="content/images/albums/'+inv[i]["song_id"]+'.png" title="'+inv[i]["song_name"]+'" id="'+(i+1)+'">');
}
```

**The problem**

Everything works fine, I get what I need (the table filled), but I get some sort of padding/margin at the bottom of every `td` with an image in it. Even if I have set width and height of the cells to `100px`, in Firebug I can see a height of `103.5px`, why this happens? I've read that it can be `DOCTYPE` causing it, but I can't remove it, id there an alternative solution?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*"but I get some sort of padding/margin at the bottom of every td **with an image** in it."*

Because img is an *inline* element, and thats why you see white space at the bottom, use this

```
table img {
    display: block;
}
```

Now this will target all the images inside `table` element, so if you want the specific ones, use a `class` instead and assign like

```
table img.your_class {
    display: block;
}
```

<kbd>[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/7MMnm/)</kbd>

In the first image, I've used `style="display: block;"` and written inline, and not for the other two, so, you will see white space for the next two images but not the first one

Comment: First of all thank you for your answer, I did like you told me and, it's better, but there's still some padding/margin inside the cells

Comment: @Xriuk I can provide you further assistance if you create a fiddle/demo for me

Comment: @Xriuk Remove the height from `<div style="height:460px;position:relative">` and see what happens :)

Comment: Oh, thanks, I've not removed it but just lowered. It worked, thanks for your time!